# Photoshop setting up wrong DPI and size when opening AI file

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, illustration, resolution, dpi

When I try to open AI file using Photoshop, it shows me wrong image size and DPI.

Original AI file data:

- CMYK
- 300 DPI
- Artboard size: **1134 x 1418 px**

Whe I open file using Photoshop, it shows me next window:
[image]

As you can see the size is wrong **3428 x 3340 px**
And sometimes the resolution is wrong to.

**Can anyone explain why it's happen and how to fix it?**

**I want to get the image of the same size and resolution from Illustrator to Photoshop.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things to note before you proceed.

1. Illustrator has a default of 72ppi. This is Illustrator's way of essentially saying that the document has no resolution, because it's a vector file, and vectors have no real resolution as such. There is no way to change this.
2. You are not actually opening the AI file, but rasterizing a PDF. Look at the import dialog. It says "Import PDF". Photoshop can't actually open AI documents. The default when saving AI files is save PDF compatible AI files. Essentially what you have is an AI document with an embedded PDF. Opening the file in Photoshop will rasterize the PDF.
3. Too long to discuss all the ins and outs here, but ppi/dpi is not the actual resolution of a raster image. It's the output resolution. The true resolution of a raster image is determined by the number of pixels it contains - i.e. more pixels = higher resolution. If you want to know more, read this: [The Myth of DPI](http://www.rideau-info.com/photos/mythdpi.html).

Armed with this information, let's now tame the beast. Here are some solutions to your problem:

If you want to import the document into Photoshop at the same pixel dimensions as the original document in Illustrator you will need to set the rsolution to 72ppi in the import dialog, and also set the Crop setting to: *Media Box*. This will ensure it uses the artboard size to rasterize the document at the expected size: 1134px × 1418px @ 72pp, which is 15.75" × 19.69".

If on the other hand you actually do want a 300ppi image, then you can set it as such in the import dialog, but also don't forget to set the *Media Box* option.  This will obviously make a larger image (with more pixels), because "higher resolution" means "more pixels". It will still be the correct size, just with more pixels: 4725px × 5908px @ 300ppi, which is 15.75" × 19.69".

Oh, and just in case you missed that, 1134/72=4725/300=15.75 and 1418/72=5908/300=19.69

I tested this with Illustrator and Photoshop. Everything works as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Everything is working as intended. Just not how you intended. The purpose of DPI is to convert between physical units and pixels values. Since illutrator uses physical units this preserves one centimeter as a centimeter and one inch as a inch.

The problem is that

A pixel can not really be a unit because it has no fixed meaning. But users like to play as it would be one. Therefore there is 3 things that are a pixels in illutstrators, pixel as in image elements on screen, pixels as in elements in raster images and pixels as units.

The unit pixel in illustrator is defined as in 1/72 of a inch to keep the system consistent. This means that when you import a image from illustrator if you want units to match the illustrator document you set the resolution to 72*. Then just after importing change it to 300 with resample unselected.

There is really no way out of this mess if people insist using pixels as units since they will eventually break some workflow. In this case you can not have both pixels and physical units stay consistent. THis method is IMHO the easiest workflow left to us**.

* Photoshop is meant for print applications. 72 DPI is the same as saying DPI not set as it gets in Photoshop. Since it didnt occour to original photoshop designers you could actually design with things other than physical units.

** the owners of standards and vector applications could have said NO to pixel units. Apropos it might be good to know that the SVG standard kind of broke the camels back. We nolonger know what a SVG pixel should have as a size.